# IIS redirect in web.config

Tags: iis-8

Hi I would like to find out how to url rewrite.

so when the user type http://test-qa or http://test-qa.domain.com  then it will redirect https url: https://test.qa.domain.com

my IISBinding

http://test-qa
http://test-qa.domain.com

Here that i have so far.

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="http://test-qa" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.qa.domain.com" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer wildcard and assuming you only have these two bindings

```
<rules>
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.qa.domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
```